# how i can use more than one text fields in ios app design

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i add 4 text fields in the view and i cant find the way to write it in viewcontroller.h 
i try this but not work

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{

UITextField *TextField1 ;
UITextField *TextField2 ;
UITextField *TextField3 ;
UITextField *TextField4 ;
}
```

then a property doesnt work with me , like this :

```
{
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField1 ;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField2 ;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField3 ;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField4 ;
 }
```

i need some help in that :(

Comment: Same question twice. seriously? Don't make new threads for same questions.

Comment: You had copy the above code from any example ? you know the important of IBOutlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use braces for properties:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField1 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField2 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField3 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField4 ;

@end
```

Also, I hope you set up connections for the controls

Comment: i do that alse but still wrong , there is a yellow mark its said:propert text field requier method , use @syunthesize...

Comment: Then do `@synthesize yourTextField` for each property in `@implementation` part

Comment: i do that befor a minute ago then appear red mark for each synthesize that sais: existing ivar 'textfield1' for_weak property 'textfield1'must be _weak ... what is that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should do it like this, the proper way .

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UITextField *TextField1 ;
IBOutlet UITextField *TextField2 ;
IBOutlet UITextField *TextField3 ;
IBOutlet UITextField *TextField4 ;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField1 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField2 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField3 ;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField4 ;
```

Well I think you are somewhere unclear about your concepts of the setter and getter methods and declaring simple variables inside an interface.

Please go through the following links :-

[Difference between @interface declaration and @property declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159725/difference-between-interface-declaration-and-property-declaration)

[Declaring IBOutlet inside or outside @interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635190/declaring-iboutlet-inside-or-outside-interface)

Hope they help your understanding of these concepts more.