# Passing delegates from singleton?

Tags: objective-c

With the help of good people here, i was able to write a singleton but cant get the delegates from it.

At the start i had a `socketConnector` class and from the `Home` class, i made an instance of him, and also got a delegates from him :

```
       socketInstance=[[SocketConnector alloc]init]; //in Home class
        socketInstance.delegate=self;
```

Than i needed to create a singleton for him, and STILL get the delegates from him to `Home`.

so i created a singleton class name : `sharedConnector` and in it i have :

```
+(sharedConnector*)defaultConnector
{
    static  sharedConnector   *myConnector ;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if( myConnector==nil  )
            myConnector=[[sharedConnector alloc]init ];
        return myConnector;
    }   
}

    - (id)init
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            connector=[[SocketConnector alloc]init]; //setting here the socketClass
        }
        return self;
    }
```

as you see i am setting here the socket class once , than to use it from `Home` class:

```
    [sharedConnector defaultConnector].connector.delegate=self; //setting delegates to home!
```

(connector has a property on the singleton)
it do work , but i dont get the delegates to home anymore . (all the delegates functions are still in Home class as they where at the start )

Comment: do you want to invoke delegate method from Singleton?

Comment: i want to get the delegates to the Home class, using the singleton, as i showed i was trying to add the delegate of the connector instance from the singltone to the home class..

Comment: case it's singleton, the init method is not invoke,when you use these code:[sharedConnector defaultConnector].connector.delegate=self; when did you invoke the init method of the singleton class ?

Comment: @junkor it is invoked. [sharedConnector defaultConnector] calls the init method on sharedConnector which in turn calls the init method of the connector object

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `connection` directly which is NOT the same as `self.connection` (which uses the synthesized method).

So change :

```
connector=[[SocketConnector alloc]init];
```

to

```
self.connector=[[SocketConnector alloc]init];
```

There is a good explanation of why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551976/986169)

Comment: will it do the delegation calling @giorashc

Comment: ohhh Great @Rant where art thou ? any insights ?