# Abandoned Memory, Leaks, Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, memory-management, instruments

I can't understand this behaviour in my app and I'm seriously thinking burn my mac NOW and start writing books of stories for children.

[image]

[image]

I have a normal Navigation Controller, and i push and pop viewcontrollers from it.

I'm doing a basic transition between views and I'm realising everything that I'm retaining or copying or whatever. But Instruments STILL identifies abandoned memory, and says that line is the responsible for that.
I can't understand. What I'm forgetting?
In Area2 I have few outles and one UIImageVIew, do I need to realising them to, in some way?

One more thing, if use Leaks inspector that same line is identified as a leak.. Really, I'm capable to destroy de entire world!

Please, can someone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong and / or forgettting?

( Iniatly I had self.navigationController instead of delegate.navigationController, but the problems occurs to! )

Just this:

```
    #import 

    @interface Area2 : UIViewController
    {
        IBOutlet UIButton * btBack;
    }

    # pragma mark - Navigation Controller
    - (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)goGaleria:(id)sender;
```

When I do Analyze ( Menu: "Product"->"Analyze" Xcode 4.2 ) give me build succeeded!

**UPDATE:**

**SOLUTION** is in the replies at @mit3z's answer! @babbidi answer!

Comment: try static analyzer, Menu: "Product"->"Analyze" Xcode 4.2

Comment: If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option).

Comment: Stupid question, but do you retain a view controller that you queried from a navigation controller somewhere else?

Comment: @DarkDust Sorry I didn't understand your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your outlets as properties and you don't release them in dealloc - then yes, you'll get a leak. It's hard to tell without seeing Area2 `@interface` declaration.

Comment: I don't see UIImageView in your declaration at all, can you post some code where you're using/creating it?

Comment: I don't have a reference to it in code, because it's just holding a image in xib file. Background image purpose only! http://i43.tinypic.com/29awghv.png As you can see I have some buttons to, just with an IBAction and image defined in the IB.

Comment: OK, i don't see any problems with your code, and since you're looking at heapshots : how do you record them, what happends if you wait a minute? does that heap growth goes away? Run Leaks instrument, does it show any leaks too?

Comment: I just want to add that also outlets without properties need releasing (in this case `btBack` should be released), presuming we're talking about iOS. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221516/does-an-iboutlet-needs-to-be-a-property-synthesized

Comment: I go to Area 2 and back, mark heap as baseline, then repeat the process, go - back - mark, and the results is similar to what is in the image above.

Yes sometimes identifies leaks to. Here a screenshot. Seriously I'm going insane. I can't understand the behaviour. Here an image with some leaks that Instruments reports when I navigate. See if anything  is familiar to you http://i40.tinypic.com/2isbp74.png and the line wich is identified as the problem, again: http://i44.tinypic.com/fkmb74.png

Comment: Try releasing 'btBack' in dealloc, IBOutlets are retained in iOS.

Comment: mit3z and @babbidi really thanks! That's solve the problem!

Now it's just identify this as a leak:
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"galeria"]];
[dict release];

One more time, it's something strange, because I do the release of the dict, and in dealloc I release the data. If it's something familiar to you and you could help, nice, I'll google it anyway!

Comment: @FábioAzevedo unless you call that block of code multiple times after initialization (alloccing `data` multiple times and releasing it just once on dealloc), it looks fine

Comment: @babbidi you're right! My bad! Sorry guys! I wasn't releasing data in dealloc! Now it's great! Again, thanks for your time!