# makeKeyAndOrderFront barfs on second use... (ARC?)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Question...

I’ve previously used this code from my MainMenu.xib to manage windows:

--

```
if([olt_MainMenu_WINDOW isVisible]){
    [olt_MainMenu_WINDOW setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
    [olt_MainMenu_WINDOW close];
}
```

...and then

```
if(olt_DoSomething_WINDOW == nil)
    if(![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DoSomething" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil])
        NSBeep();
if(olt_DoSomething_WINDOW != nil)
    [olt_DoSomething_WINDOW makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

--

...then go back to my window in my MainMenu.xib:

--

```
if([olt_DoSomething_WINDOW isVisible]){
    [olt_DoSomething_WINDOW setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
    [olt_DoSomething_WINDOW close];
}
```

...and then

```
if(olt_MainMenu_WINDOW == nil)
    if(![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil])
        NSBeep();
if(olt_MainMenu_WINDOW != nil)
    [olt_MainMenu_WINDOW makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

--

but if I try to makeKeyAndOrderFront the DoSomething window a second time, it barfs with exc_bad_access (code=1 ...

I can makeKeyAndOrderFront the MainMenu more than once but not any others. What am I missing?

Yes, 'Release When Closed’ is not selected in the Attributes inspector for the window. This is the first time I've used this with ARC, could it be related to that?

Comment: Run the Analyzer. Any warnings? Fix them. Then run with zombies enabled. Any zombie errors? Fix them, or edit your question to include the errors. (See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) or [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects.html) for ways to enable zombies.)

Comment: I think this SO question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221516/does-an-iboutlet-needs-to-be-a-property-synthesized

Comment: Analyzer returns no warnings, but I get a hit with zombie: '2015-04-27 14:06:22.730 six[4660:97785] *** -[DoSomething windowDidBecomeKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6080000a5a60
(lldb)'

Comment: Henrietta, please take a screenshot of the window's retain / release history in Instruments and post it.

Comment: Where and how are you storing the DoSomething window (controller) ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [reference for `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:), I'm going to guess that you have a weak `IBOutlet` to the `NSWindow` top level object in the doSomething nib.  Since you're not passing something like `&myArray` and instead using `topLevelObjects:nil`, it's pretty clear that "it is necessary to keep a strong reference to them by using IBOutlets."

> **Discussion**
>
> Unlike legacy methods, the objects [*topLevelObjects-ed.*] adhere to the standard cocoa memory management rules; it is necessary to keep a strong reference to them by using IBOutlets or holding a reference to the array to prevent the nib contents from being deallocated.
>
> Outlets to top-level objects should be strong references to demonstrate ownership and prevent deallocation.

You need:

`@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *olt_DoSomething_WINDOW;`

... or to otherwise keep a strong reference to the window.  `IBOutlets` are generally weak because they are view elements retained by their superview that you do not need the controller retaining, but your `NSWindow` here has no retaining owner unless you explicitly create one.  So it would be a case where you actually want a strong IBOutlet.

Comment: Thank you Steve, Chris and Rob. @property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *olt_DoSomething_WINDOW; works. Also, to update the code to work as posted above (a few years ago) I needed to change 'setReleasedWhenClosed' to 'orderOut'.  :)

Comment: BTW, `strong` is implicit when nothing else is specified, but it's nice to be explicit in this case.